# imageio.jar works as standalone but not as a web project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, javax.imageio

I am having a spring mvc project with the basic pom.

I also have imageio.jar in build path.

```
    String format="tif";
System.out.println(format);
Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO
        .getImageReadersByFormatName(format);
System.out.println(readers.hasNext());

Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO
        .getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff");
System.out.println(writers.hasNext());
```

When the above code is executes as a stand alone program i get the output as follows

```
tif
true
true
```

but when i add it to a Spring mvc controller mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{format}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String test(@PathVariable String format) {
        System.out.println(format);
        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO
                .getImageReadersByFormatName(format);
        System.out.println(readers.hasNext());

        Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO
                .getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff");
        System.out.println(writers.hasNext());

        return "Done";

    }
```

i get the output as

```
tif
false
false
```

Please help me in solving this issue.i really dono what is the problem.

I have a lot of work to be done based on this.

Comment: same api you have in buildpath what you tested?

Comment: TIFF support is provided through extension support with jars placed within the JVMs ext directory, it's not enough to put them in the class path

Comment: @MadProgrammer ...or you could use something similar to [this](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app). I wrote it for my own library, but it should work for the JAI imageio plugins as well. Your solution is probably the easiest though. :-)

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014969/tess4j-with-spring-mvc/22904645#22904645) for your previous question. ImageIO jar works for both standalone and web project.