# Tess4J working correctly from sources but not from JAR

Tags: java, dll, jar, tesseract, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using `maven` as build system and `IntelliJ` as development environment in `Java` and I want to do `OCR`.

I added `tess4j` as maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version> <!-- 4.2.1 -->
</dependency>
```

I wrote the following code to use `Tesseract`:

```
public class OpticalCharacterRecognition
{
    private static final String TESS_DATA = "tessdata";
    public static final String DATA_FOLDER = getProgramDirectory() + separator + TESS_DATA;
    public static final String LANGUAGE = "eng";

    private ITesseract instance;

    public OpticalCharacterRecognition()
    {
        instance = new Tesseract();
        instance.setLanguage(LANGUAGE);
        instance.setDatapath(DATA_FOLDER);
    }

    // ...
}
```

When running from `IntelliJ`, everything works fine. When running from `JAR`, the `OCR` doesn't recognize text correctly on my machine (e.g. the recognized text is an empty string but in `IntelliJ` it would be correctly recognized despite the image being the same) but it's hard to reproduce with a minimal test case for some reason. I'm just using `instance.doOCR(bufferedImage)`, nothing too special.

[I also tried invoking `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030735/3764804) before `doOCR()` but it didn't help.

<s>Some users of the `JAR` however get this error:</s>

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI
```

This suggests that some files were missing from the `JAR` but they are not since `Tesseract` extracts and loads the `DLL`s from the `JAR` for use.

Does [installing a `Tesseract` distribution](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/) matter?

(Fixed by installing [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587))

My `pom.xml` build plugins:

```
<!-- Generate Target JAR -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <!-- Drop the META-INF/maven folder -->
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>${libraries.directory}</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>LauncherClient</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Built-By>Me</Built-By>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<!-- Copy JAR libraries to target folder -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${libraries.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm a bit desperate due to these weird issues so I'm not sure anymore what else to try to make it work flawlessly. All users (including myself) are only on `Windows`. I'm on `Windows 10 Pro`.

Comment: read this forum. https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j/issues/95